# How to resize 45deg element to the viewport boundaries

Tags: css

I have an unusual problem that i am struggling to solve. I have one element on my page, which I want to serve as a background. I want it to be rotated by 45 degrees, and regardless of the viewport's width, I would like the left and right corner of this square to respectively touch left and right edge of the page. so in other words, the width of the square must be responsive. I don't really know how to calculate the width of the square so the corners don't go beyond the screen area. Is something like this even achievable in CSS?

Here's my code:

```css
.container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vw;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
}

.square {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vw;
  background: #000;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0) rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

All together on jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y10hkoja/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer will involve basic Pythagorean geometry - `a^2 + b^2 = c^2`.

Since you are rotating a square, and you want the two points of your square to be `100vw`, this is your value of `c`, so `c^2 = 10,000vw`.

But, also, since you are dealing with a square, a = b, we'll redefine `a` as `x` to give us a formula of `2x^2 = 10,000vw`. Simplify to `x^2 = 5000vw`. The value then of `x = Sqrt(5000)vw` or ~`70.7106781187vw`.

```css
.bg-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 70.7106781187vw; /* css can't calc sqrt so use calculator */
  height: 70.7106781187vw;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
}

.bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 70.7106781187vw;
  height: 70.7106781187vw;
  background: #000;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0) rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-wrapper">
  <div class="bg"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easier way to achieve this using gradient and without complex calculation:

```css
body {
  background:
    linear-gradient(to top    left ,transparent 49.8%,#fff 50%) top    left,
    linear-gradient(to top    right,transparent 49.8%,#fff 50%) top    right,
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 49.8%,#fff 50%) bottom right,
    linear-gradient(to bottom left ,transparent 49.8%,#fff 50%) bottom left,
    #000;
  background-size:50vh 50vh;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  margin:0;
  height:100vh;
}
```